# Ubuntu Chrome `www.apple.com` video quality problem

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, gstreamer, quicktime

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, Google Chrome 18.

I want to know why the video is so blurry.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because videos on apple.com are streamed in a format you can't decode very well without quicktime. Now, quicktime is only supported for windows and mac os x, that's why it's appearing so blurry on your ubuntu desktop.

Comment: No solution for better quality then??

Comment: You could try firefox with the quicktime plugin. That should work better.